# missing data for column with sql COPY

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, psycopg2, sqlbulkcopy

I'm working on Jupyter notebook.

I have the following json file:

```
{"num_songs": 1, "artist_id": "ARJIE2Y1187B994AB7", "artist_latitude": null, "artist_longitude": null, "artist_location": "", "artist_name": "Line Renaud", "song_id": "SOUPIRU12A6D4FA1E1", "title": "Der Kleine Dompfaff", "duration": 152.92036, "year": 0}
```

I want to load it into a table using copy statement.

I've created my table like this:

```
song_table_create = (""" CREATE TABLE songs (song_id varchar, title varchar, artist_id varchar, year int, duration float)""")
```

Here my copy statement:

```
test_statement = """copy songs (song_id, title, artist_id, year, duration) from '/home/workspace/data/song_data/A/B/C/TRABCRU128F423F449.json';"""
cur.execute(test_statement)
```

when running it I got the following error

```
DataError: missing data for column "title"
CONTEXT:  COPY songs, line 1: "{"num_songs": 1, "artist_id": "AR8IEZO1187B99055E", "artist_latitude": null, "artist_longitude": nul..."
```

What's wrong?

Comment: make sure you are using the correct file. you may do but always good to double check.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue few weeks back and first option helped me to resolve my issue.

I will check for the following options

1. Space character (one or many) have escaped with backslash at the end of unquoted value.
2. One or many lines of your JSON has 4 or fewer space characters means your delimiter.

This document link may help you to understand. [COPY command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html#AEN69025)